# How to reuse a websocket channel in threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, coroutine

I am looking at using websockets in my client (browser) - server (Python) application and I have a hard time to understand how to reuse a websocket channel across threads.

My application will have a few threads, each independently generating some data which I would like to push to the browser. The [Getting Started examples](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) make it clear that once a browser connects to the server, a specific function is ran (I copy the example from the linked docs):

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets

async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
        await websocket.send(now)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

start_server = websockets.serve(time, '127.0.0.1', 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Now let's say I have a function (worker)

```
def thread1(an_existing_webocket):
    while True:
        an_existing_webocket.send("1")
        print("1")
        time.sleep(1)
```

which I would like to start via `threading.Thread(target=thread1, args=(an_initialized_websocket,)).start()`.

**How do these two worlds (websockets using coroutines and `threading`) coexist?** And more specifically: what is the websocket I can pass to the workers so that they can use it to send messages upstream?

In other words, how should I create the `an_initialized_websocket` above?

Comment: you wrote *I would like to start* - have you started and what is your actual issue?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: starting the thread is not the problem (via the provided code). What I do not understand is what exactly is the websocket object I can use in the threads (the `an_existing_websocket` passed to the thread)